# ASP Replace in PHP?

Tags: php, asp-classic, replace, str-replace

Hi I want to do a simple replace using str_replace, like Classic ASP.

```
$strName="Blush / Black";
$strName=$strName(str_replace("/","&"));
```

It should read, when echo:

Blush & Black. I get an Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$strName="Blush / Black";
$strName=str_replace("/","&", $strName);
```

Comment: Why do you declare the string twice even INSIDE the string?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid You should learn about what functions are and how they are used ;)

Comment: You need to pass the string to the function which then returns a completely new string with the replacements, `str_replace` doesn't update the old variable. PHP is different to ASP, perhaps you should read up on it via the php.net website.

Comment: Think about it logically: `$strname`= the value of replace "/" with "&" inside $strname

Answer (score 2):

```
$strName=$strName(str_replace("/","&"));
         ^---- error
```

you're using a "variable function". In this case, telling PHP to execute a function called `Bush / Black`, which is not a valid function name, and also doesn't exist.

What you want is:

```
   $strName = str_replace('/', '&', 'Blush / Black');
```

Comment: Yeah, like the answer above too. Thanks for this. Voted.